# Not able to access control value when serializing by jquery

Tags: jquery, serialization

A very strange problem came to me. In one my senario I am implementing autosave feature. wherein i am using jquery serializer. Also i have used timer which calls a function on regular interval basis. that function perform an ajax call(post method) and sends the serialize string to the server. On server i capture the form value and store in database.

I Have used infragistic web html editor control.At the first time serialize string dont include the value of editor,but next time when timer function again serialize the form , then it include editor content.. very strange .. any reply will be highly appreciated.. thanks below is the sample code.

```
timerfunction() {
    var str = $("#wrapper input,select,textarea,MainContent_USCWebHtmlEditor_t_a,MainContent_USCWebHtmlEditor_tw").not(':button').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<%= GetPageUrl() %>?autosave=true",
      data: str,
      success: function (msg) {
        ProcessPostAutosave(msg);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: First thought is that this is firing off before the document is ready, so `#wrapper input`, etc does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

`MainContent_USCWebHtmlEditor_t_a` and `MainContent_USCWebHtmlEditor_tw` are wrong selectors

if these are the id's of the components you should add a `#` before or when they are classes you should add a `.` before

also mind that you grab all the `<input>` within `#wrapper` but all the other elements will also be taken from outside the `#wrapper`

if you want to solve that you could do

```
var context = $("#wrapper")
var str = $("input,select,textarea", context).not(':button').serialize();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I have tried both. it is capturing the content of editor in next interval. but in first it even dont include the content of editor in serialized string.